# NamedList<Object> Throws Class cast Exception

Tags: java, collections

I want to form an Object of NamedList as this  :

```
response={numFound=57279026,start=0,docs=[SolrDocument{timestamp_update=Thu Jan 01 01:00:00 CET 1970}]}}
```

When I do that I am getting an exception thrown when my code tries to access the result: `SolrDocumentList results = response.getResults();`

```
**java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.solr.common.util.SimpleOrderedMap cannot be cast to org.apache.solr.common.SolrDocumentList**
```

How should I create the NamedList, so that it doesn't throw an exception

Here is my way of doing it:

```java
NamedList<Object> nl = new SimpleOrderedMap<>();
private static  Map<String, Object> solrDocumentMap= new HashMap<>();
solrDocumentMap.put("timestamp_update", TIMESTAMP_UPDATE);
solrDocument= new SolrDocument(solrDocumentMap);
solrDocumentList.add(solrDocument);

nl.add("numFound", "57279026");
nl.add("start", "0");
 nl.add("docs", solrDocumentList);

 NamedList<Object> nl1 = new NamedList<>(Collections.singletonMap("response", nl));
 response.setResponse(nl1);
```

**Here is the in built class of QueryResponse which is casting the response to SolarDocument**

```java
  public void setResponse(NamedList<Object> res) {
        super.setResponse(res);

        for(int i = 0; i < res.size(); ++i) {
            String n = res.getName(i);
            if ("responseHeader".equals(n)) {
                this._header = (NamedList)res.getVal(i);
            } else if ("response".equals(n)) {
                this._results = (SolrDocumentList)res.getVal(i);
            } else if ("sort_values".equals(n)) {
                this._sortvalues = (NamedList)res.getVal(i);
            } else if ("facet_counts".equals(n)) {
                this._facetInfo = (NamedList)res.getVal(i);
            } else if ("debug".equals(n)) {
                this._debugInfo = (NamedList)res.getVal(i);
                this.extractDebugInfo(this._debugInfo);
            } else if ("grouped".equals(n)) {
                this._groupedInfo = (NamedList)res.getVal(i);
                this.extractGroupedInfo(this._groupedInfo);
            } else if ("expanded".equals(n)) {
                NamedList map = (NamedList)res.getVal(i);
                this._expandedResults = map.asMap(1);
            } else if ("highlighting".equals(n)) {
                this._highlightingInfo = (NamedList)res.getVal(i);
                this.extractHighlightingInfo(this._highlightingInfo);
            } else if ("spellcheck".equals(n)) {
                this._spellInfo = (NamedList)res.getVal(i);
                this.extractSpellCheckInfo(this._spellInfo);
            } else if ("clusters".equals(n)) {
                this._clusterInfo = (ArrayList)res.getVal(i);
                this.extractClusteringInfo(this._clusterInfo);
            } else if ("suggest".equals(n)) {
                this._suggestInfo = (Map)res.getVal(i);
                this.extractSuggesterInfo(this._suggestInfo);
            } else if ("stats".equals(n)) {
                this._statsInfo = (NamedList)res.getVal(i);
                this.extractStatsInfo(this._statsInfo);
            } else if ("terms".equals(n)) {
                this._termsInfo = (NamedList)res.getVal(i);
                this.extractTermsInfo(this._termsInfo);
            } else if ("moreLikeThis".equals(n)) {
                this._moreLikeThisInfo = (NamedList)res.getVal(i);
            } else if ("nextCursorMark".equals(n)) {
                this._cursorMarkNext = (String)res.getVal(i);
            }
        }

        if (this._facetInfo != null) {
            this.extractFacetInfo(this._facetInfo);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally found a solution, I hope this helps everyone. I got the response from Solr in XML format and read the file and parsed it with the XMLResponseParser. Somehow JsonParser is not working for Solar and if you use java deserialization, there is an existing bug in Solr for incompatibility.

This works well with the internal typecasting of query Response class as well.

```java
protected QueryResponse getResponse(String fileName) throws IOException {

        Path path = Paths.get(resDir + "/" + fileName);
        InputStream body= new FileInputStream(path.toFile());
        NamedList<Object> result= processResponse(body, null);
        QueryResponse response = new QueryResponse();
        response.setResponse(result);
        return response;
    }

    private NamedList<Object> processResponse(InputStream body, Object o) {
        XMLResponseParser parser= new XMLResponseParser();
        NamedList<Object> result= parser.processResponse(body, "UTF-8");
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similare problem using Solrj 9.4.0.
I found another solution by converting the given Map manually and create a new instance of SuggesterResult.

```
public void mySuggestion(String input){

    SolrClient client; // create a Http2SolrClient

    SolrQuery suggQuery = new SolrQuery();
    suggQuery.setRequestHandler("/suggest");
    suggQuery.setParam("suggest", true);
    suggQuery.setParam("suggest.q", input);

    try {
        QueryRequest qreq = new QueryRequest(suggQuery, SolrRequest.METHOD.GET);
        NamedList<Object> res = client.request(qreq);

        for (int i = 0; i < res.size(); i++) {
            String n = res.getName(i);
            if ("suggest".equals(n)) {
                _suggestInfo = (Map<String, NamedList<Object>>) res.getVal(i);
                extractSuggesterInfo(_suggestInfo);
            }
        }
      } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
}

private void extractSuggesterInfo(Map<String, NamedList<Object>> suggestInfo) {
        suggestResponse = new SuggesterResponse(convertMapToNamedList(suggestInfo));
    }

private NamedList<NamedList<Object>> convertMapToNamedList(Map<String, NamedList<Object>> map) {
    NamedList<NamedList<Object>> list = new NamedList<>();

    for (Map.Entry<String, NamedList<Object>> entry : map.entrySet()) {

        String key = entry.getKey();
        NamedList<Object> nl = entry.getValue();

        list.add(key, nl);
    }
    return list;
}
```